# Is Chuck Barris's work as a CIA hit-man a fantasy?

Tags: dangerous-mind

The movie [Confessions of a Dangerous Mind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0270288/) is based on the book of the same name, which is the autobiography of Chuck Barris.

Barris was the creator of TV shows such as The Dating Game and The Gong Show. The movie (and also the book) describe how he had a second job -- secretly -- as a CIA hit-man who killed 33 people during his time served.

Reviewers such as [Roger Ebert](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/confessions-of-a-dangerous-mind-2003) have noted that the hit-man part of the autobiography might not be true. Indeed, after viewing the movie, I took the hit-man segments as **fantasy symbolizing Barris's struggle with committing to his girlfriend and the career he has chosen**.

Is there any evidence, either in-universe or otherwise, that offers insight as to whether Chuck Barris really did serve as a hit-man for the CIA?

Comment: I assume, though, you primarily mean the movie-Barris and not the real one, right?

Comment: I'm asking about both the movie character and the real guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Out of universe*, I don't know of any evidence to suggest he was in the *CIA* other than his own claims, which he doesn't substantiate.

[The CIA themselves said](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2003/mar/03/artsfeatures.fiction):

> 'We make it a practice not to say who is or isn't in the CIA. But in
>   this case we'll make an exception. Chuck Barris is not.'

Of course, you could immediately argue that *obviously they would say that about one of their agents*. But now we're starting to get in to real tin-foil hat territory!

He's presented no claims that he is remotely involved with the CIA and as the burden of proof really needs to rest on his shoulders, I'll say he **was not involved with the CIA**.

*In universe*, the character in the film does take missions with the CIA, including assisting the German-American agent Keeler to murder *Colbert* - so in universe, he is clearly involved. But this is obviously based on the autobiography, which as already stated doesn't appear to have an out of universe source of truth.

Comment: +1 Very nice CIA quote/source and explanation. Thank you. By "in universe" I was wondering if there are any clues in the movie that the CIA stuff is fake... For example, I think the way his girlfriend laughs at him when he tells her about his supposed CIA work suggests that she sees through it all, though that's more my opinion than a tangible clue. Anyway, thanks again!